# Um serviço pode ser morto pelo android?

Tags: android

Eu sei que a depender do tempo que uma *Activity* fique em estado de *onPause()* e caso o dispositivo precise liberar memória ele irá matar essa *Activity*. Gostaria de saber se o mesmo ocorre com o serviço que roda em background? Quando a *Activity* é morta o serviço também será morto?

Eu tenho um serviço que faz um update de localização utilizando a API do Google Maps de tempos em tempos, porém eu acredito que depois de muito tempo ligado, e ao usuário ir usando outros aplicativos ele é morto.

Comment: Tem como detalhar a forma com que esse serviço roda em background para que possamos ajudar da melhor forma?

Comment: Claro, editarei a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Ao contrário do que a documentação parece sugerir, para liberar memória o sistema [não mata a Activity](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html) e sim o processo inteiro do seu aplicativo. Geralmente os serviços são mortos junto, pois pertencem ao mesmo processo (embora seja possível definir que rodem em processos separados, apesar de pouco comum).

É possível [reduzir as chances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696861/how-can-we-prevent-a-service-from-being-killed-by-os) do serviço ser morto, colocando-o para rodar em "foreground" (primeiro plano). Mas não é muito desejável pois faz torna o usuário ciente do serviço em execução, através de uma notificação na barra de notificações.

O ideal dependendo da situação seria definir que o serviço deve ser reiniciado mesmo em caso do processo morrer. Isso é feito através de flags como por exemplo `START_STICKY`:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //**Seu código**
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Eu já defini isso, porém acredito que ele morre... Pois paro de receber os updates, depois de um longo tempo..

Comment: Tem também o START_NOT_STICKY e o START_REDELIVER_INTENT, você chegou a tentá-los? Além disso, talvez seja bom você incluir na pergunta o código do seu serviço, para que possamos entender melhor o que está acontecendo.